# Why can't Access use my UNC path under RunAs?

Tags: ms-access, active-directory, vba, ms-access-2010

I am adapting an existing shared file-based Access app to run a local front-end copy against SQL Server data.  There are two types of user, differentiated by whether the PC they use is part of the AD domain.  All users have a login for this domain, but some run their PCs outside it (logging on using the PC's local domain) and just have mapped drives inside.  On these, I am running Access using the command
`RunAs /netonly /user:ADDomain\ADUser "MSACCESS.EXE File.accdb`.

All seems OK except actions requiring access to locations inside the AD domain.  I've tried using the drive mappings and UNC paths but neither works.  The step that fails is Export to Excel where the output file destination is in the AD domain, and the error is "2302: Microsoft Access can't save the output data to the file you've selected".  Searching for the error code suggests that RunAs is the problem, but it's necessary for access to the data (in SQL Server, inside the AD domain, and accessible only via the AD security groups granted to the domain user).

I can't think of a way to side-step the problem, so does anyone know a solution?  Any ideas gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

Answer turned out to be buried in IE options: local intranet settings needed the 'site' (path) added to the zone, and the zone needed the 'include all network paths (UNCs)' box checked.